# "Fallback" rule in Webpack config

Tags: webpack, webpack-config

Is there a way to define a "fallback" rule for Webpack, so that if nothing else matched from `.module.rules`, then this rule is applied?

I have tried specifying a rule in last position with a very permissive `test:`, however it seems to take precedence regardless of its position (first, last, also tried within`oneOf`).

Example:

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        oneOf: [
          { test: /\.ts$/i, loader: "ts-loader" },
          { test: /\.ttf$/i, loader: "url-loader" },
          { test: /.+/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'd have liked everything that's not a `.ts` or `.ttf` to be loaded via `file-loader`, but actually it seems to be applied even for `.ts` files for example.

Answer (score -1):

That happens because the regular expression in the last test is matching all file extensions, including the ones you would like ignored.

In order to avoid that, you'll need to filter out the known/expected extensions from the catch-all test.

For example:

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
       { test: /\.ts$/i, loader: "ts-loader" },
       { test: /\.ttf$/i, loader: "url-loader" },
       { test: /\.(?!ts|ttf)([\w]+)/i, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: But the rules are within a `oneOf` block, shouldn't that only match one rule? I.e. for `.ts` files, first rule matches, so I'd expect it doesn't even try matching the others...

Comment: I can only assume `oneOf` is ignored in your example, as there is no main condition. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleoneof

Comment: I have edited my answer and removed the `oneOf` bit

Comment: Oh, I might be using `oneOf` incorrectly, let me experiment a bit... An "inverse regex" is unfortunately not really an option because the real config contains around 20 rules, some of them with quite complex regexps, exclusions, etc. so creating and maintaining an inverse would be a nightmare